# How to install XCode on a MacBook Air without a DVD drive?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xcode, macbook-air

I just bought a new MacBook Air and would like to install XCode and the Developer Tools. XCode usually comes on the Snow Leopard DVD, but the MacBook Air does not have a DVD drive, so it comes with a USB stick with Snow Leopard and iLife. I'm not sure if it comes with XCode.

How should I install XCode on my new MacBook Air?

### Solution

The MacBook Air re-install USB stick does not come with XCode, so you will need to download the XCode installer from the [Apple Developer website](http://developer.apple.com/). You will be able to mount the installer and install it without needing to boot from a disc. You won't even need to restart! =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download Xcode from http://developer.apple.com (you need a free developer account). It's a newer version anyway.

---

If you have another computer, you can insert the DVD there and copy the installer files across the network, or to an USB disk you can connect to your Macbook Air.

Answer (score 1):

[It's available for free on the Mac App Store.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12)

Comment: While downloading it from the Mac App Store will work for Lion installations, the OP specified Snow Leopard.

Comment: You are correct. XCode 4 is _now_ available via the Mac App Store.